# Rails tests are passing but server refuses to start on production due to syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, minitest

This is one weird issue I am facing. All the test cases are passing on the CI/CD but there's a syntax error in one of the files.

And when this changes goes to production the server refuses to start.

Is this the correct expected behaviour?

What are my options to do some kind of sanity check for syntax-related mistakes so that CI/CD fails and doesn't let people go ahead with deployment?

Comment: Do you have [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) in terms of Ruby versions? I got burned several times in my former life as a PHP dev when I delivered code to clients and they proceeded to deploy it to some shitty web hotel running an ancient version of PHP.

Comment: SyntaxError will absolutely come with a stacktrace. Reviewing this will help you determine where the error is. If you cannot determine why then post the stacktrace and offending code here along with the applicable details including ruby version(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely are not loading the offending class when you're running tests (meaning - you're most probably not testing code that requires loading of that class).

The different behavior is most likely due to different config between production and test env, namely this:

```
config.cache_classes = true
# or, depending on your rails version (see: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#eager-loading) 
config.eager_load = true
```

Production usually preloads all the classes before starting a server, in development and test environments "lazy loading" is the name of the game (meaning classes are loaded when they are needed).

Since your CI/CD is running all specs anyway, consider such config in your `config/enviroments/test.rb`:

```
config.cache_classes = ENV.fetch("CI", false)
# or
config.eager_load = ENV.fetch("CI", false)
```

(most CI services are setting `CI=true` env variable, if you don't have it - you need to implement a way to "tell" your code that it's running on CI.

Comment: Actually the default for the test environment in Rails is `config.cache_classes = true`  although Spring can modify this. This is true in Rails 7 and pretty much as far back as I can remember. Code reloading doesn't actually make much sense in the test environment unless you're using a preloader like Spring. It's not an interactive session where you need to hotswap code like when you're monkeying around in the console.

Comment: The modern setting is also `config.enable_reloading` and `config.cache_classes` is just provided for legacy support. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#eager-loading

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the answer.

Comment: eager loading on test environment fixed the issue for me.